# How to distinguish inline numbers from OLE Automation date numbers in OpenXML SpreadSheet?

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have to consume some `xlsx` documents. I've read [Reading a date from xlsx using open xml sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176832/reading-a-date-from-xlsx-using-open-xml-sdk) and http://www.dotnetperls.com/fromoadate. Most of my columns are texts (shared strings), but there are some numbers (integer numbers), and I have also some dates and date-times.
I'm using OpenXML SDK 2.5.

My problem is that I don't know how to distinguish the actual numbers from the dates. Both of them has `DataType` of `null`, and the textual number representation is in the `Text` property of the cell.

Some code:

```
  using (var xlsxStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Checklist.xlsx"))
  using (var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xlsxStream, false))
  {
    var workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    var sharedStringTable = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
    var worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
    var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
    string text;
    foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
    {
      foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
      {
        if (c.CellValue != null)
        {
          text = c.CellValue.Text;
          if (c.DataType != null)
          {
            if (c.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
              int tableIndex = int.Parse(text);
              text = sharedStringTable.ChildElements[tableIndex].InnerText;
            }
            // note: the date cells do not have c.DataType.Value == CellValues.Date
            // Their c.DataType is null, if they are OLE Automation date numbers
          }
          // So here I am, and I'd need to know if the number supposed to be an
          // OLE Automation date or a number, so I can transform it if needed.
          //if (it's a date) // <- ?????
          //{
          //    double dateDouble = double.Parse(text);
          //    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(dateDouble);
          //    text = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
          //}
          Console.Write(text + " ");
        }
        else
        {
          Console.Write("NULL" + " ");
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just came across similar issue and it is not easy to check whether a cell contains date/time value, see [Using cell format to determine a cell contains date/time value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730152/what-indicates-an-office-open-xml-cell-contains-a-date-time-value), but the issue doesn't end with built-in number formats, I needed to handle custom formats too. There are no utilities in OpenXML SDK 2.5 to help, so I had to write my own (doesn't support Thai date/time formats).

```cs
public class ExcelHelper
{
    static uint[] builtInDateTimeNumberFormatIDs = new uint[] { 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 45, 46, 47, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58 };
    static Dictionary<uint, NumberingFormat> builtInDateTimeNumberFormats = builtInDateTimeNumberFormatIDs.ToDictionary(id => id, id => new NumberingFormat { NumberFormatId = id });
    static Regex dateTimeFormatRegex = new Regex(@"((?=([^[]*\[[^[\]]*\])*([^[]*[ymdhs]+[^\]]*))|.*\[(h|mm|ss)\].*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static Dictionary<uint, NumberingFormat> GetDateTimeCellFormats(WorkbookPart workbookPart)
    {
        var dateNumberFormats = workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats
            .Descendants<NumberingFormat>()
            .Where(nf => dateTimeFormatRegex.Match(nf.FormatCode.Value).Success)
            .ToDictionary(nf => nf.NumberFormatId.Value);

        var cellFormats = workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats
            .Descendants<CellFormat>();

        var dateCellFormats = new Dictionary<uint, NumberingFormat>();
        uint styleIndex = 0;
        foreach (var cellFormat in cellFormats)
        {
            if (cellFormat.ApplyNumberFormat != null && cellFormat.ApplyNumberFormat.Value)
            {
                if (dateNumberFormats.ContainsKey(cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value))
                {
                    dateCellFormats.Add(styleIndex, dateNumberFormats[cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value]);
                }
                else if (builtInDateTimeNumberFormats.ContainsKey(cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value))
                {
                    dateCellFormats.Add(styleIndex, builtInDateTimeNumberFormats[cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value]);
                }
            }

            styleIndex++;
        }

        return dateCellFormats;
    }

    // Usage Example
    public static bool IsDateTimeCell(WorkbookPart workbookPart, Cell cell)
    {
        if (cell.StyleIndex == null)
            return false;

        var dateTimeCellFormats = ExcelHelper.GetDateTimeCellFormats(workbookPart);

        return dateTimeCellFormats.ContainsKey(cell.StyleIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. You achieve more than what I need. The short answer to my question is that I **have to pay attention to the style attributes and look up the style cross references and decide the format based on that**. The short incomplete list in Mark baker's answer in the other topic you linked gives a good indication. I haven't had time to try out the solution yet though. Since I knew the fixed schema of my 7 different XLS inputs, my ugly workaround was to hard wire the schemas into my code.

Comment: Now that was extremely helpful!

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer to the "what cells are dates" question I have found in a several hours of web research.

Comment: Thanks for this, I found that it fails if there are no NumberingFormats, so I added a check for this on line 9 (first line of GetDateTimeCellFormats): `if (workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats == null) ...`

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a version of the above accepted answer to make it work for a failing scenario.
It fails in a scenario where your cell is of `Currency` type with the built-in format applied - `&quot;$&quot;#,##0_);[Red]\(&quot;$&quot;#,##0\)`

The regex `((?=([^[]*\[[^[\]]*\])*([^[]*[ymdhs]+[^\]]*))|.*\[(h|mm|ss)\].*)` (in the accepted answer) parses the above mentioned built-in format as well, which in turn makes it a datetime cell & the value returned is date time value, instead of a currency value.

I have modified the `GetDateTimeCellFormats` method little bit, so that the regex doesn't interfere with any of built-in formats not belonging to date/time/datetime.

```
        var dateCellFormats = new Dictionary<uint, NumberingFormat>();
        uint styleIndex = 0;
        foreach (var cellFormat in cellFormatList)
        {
            if (cellFormat.ApplyNumberFormat == null || !cellFormat.ApplyNumberFormat.Value)
            {
                styleIndex++;
                continue;
            }

            var numFmtId = cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value;
            if (numFmtId < 164)
            {
                if (builtInDateTimeNumberFormats.ContainsKey(cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value))
                    dateCellFormats.Add(styleIndex, builtInDateTimeNumberFormats[cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value]);
            }
            else
            {
                if (dateNumberFormatsDict.ContainsKey(cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value))
                    dateCellFormats.Add(styleIndex, dateNumberFormatsDict[cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value]);
            }
            styleIndex++;
        }
```

Rest all code remains same.

Comment: I moved away from that code from a long time now, but this is a great addition.