# Solve datetime issue when reading Excel file using Open XML

Tags: c#, openxml

I want to read Excel file with exact cell values using Open XML but I am getting `integer` value instead of `datetime` cell value.

Comment: OpenXML stores dates as the number of days from 1 Jan 1900. See [Reading a date from xlsx using open xml sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176832/reading-a-date-from-xlsx-using-open-xml-sdk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a date from xlsx using open xml sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176832/reading-a-date-from-xlsx-using-open-xml-sdk)