# c# Writing data from excel file to text file using excel cell formatting in

Tags: c#, wpf, string.format

I have a WPF that reads an excel file and removes hidden characters and writes the data as pipe delimited to a text file.  Works pretty good.  Now I am trying to keep the cell formatting that excel has.  For test purposes I have a zip code field in excel.  The cell has value 047300134 and a custom format of 00000-0000.  I would like the data written to be 04730-0134.  The only process I saw that using String.Format.  Here is how I tried to code it.

```
dfCellFormat = range[NumRow, lngColCnt].DisplayFormat;
strNumberFormat = dfCellFormat.NumberFormat;
strCellData = Convert.ToString(values[NumRow, lngColCnt]);
strNumberFormat = "{0:" + strNumberFormat.Replace("0","#") + "}";
strCellData = String.Format(strNumberFormat, strCellData);
```

The result is just 047300134, the format is not applied.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what happened but someone had sent this link to me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929799/how-to-get-cell-value-with-applied-formatting-formatted-cell-value-with-openxm/8955747#8955747.  Now I do not see that comment.

Anyway that was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this statement

    dfCellFormat = range[NumRow, lngColCnt].DisplayFormat;

causes my process to be very slow?  I have a file that has 2500 rows and 67 columns.  Without this code it takes seconds, with it minutes, like 5.  Any ideas?

Comment: I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929799/how-to-get-cell-value-with-applied-formatting-formatted-cell-value-with-openxm/8955747#8955747 that solved my issue.