# Determine cell formats (date, currency, custom etc.) in xlsx using OpenXml

Tags: excel, format, openxml

I am using `OpenXml` to parse text from `xlsx` files.

Straightforward text and numbers extract as expected, but anything with cell formatting such as a `date`, `currency` or `custom` `format` are not extracting as per the displayed text in Excel.  This wouldn't be a problem if I could easily identify the cell format in code and then take the relevant action, but I cannot find it anywhere!

Example.xlsx file has:

---

Cell A1 - Date Format *14/03/2001

Inputting text '14/11/2018' into cell A1 displays as '14/11/2018'

**Local Variables:**

> c.CellValue = "43418"
>   c.CellValue.InnerText = "43418"
>  
>   c.Prefix = "x"
>   c.StyleIndex = "2"
>   c.DataType Nothing
>   c.CellFormula Nothing

Required value = `'14/11/2018'`

---

Cell A2 - Currency Format (Symbol £, 2 decimal places)

Inputting text '2000' into cell A2 displays as '£2,000.00'

**Local Variables:**

> c.CellValue = "2000"
>   c.CellValue.InnerText = "2000"
>   c.Prefix = "x"
>   c.StyleIndex = "3"
>   c.DataType Nothing
>   c.CellFormula Nothing

Required value = `'£2,000.00'`

---

Cell A3 - Custom Format "ABC-"@

Inputting text 'P-100' into cell A3 displays as 'ABC-P-100'

**Local Variables:**

> OpenXml Cell.CellValue = "P-100"
>   OpenXml Cell.CellValue.InnerText = "P-100"
>   OpenXml Cell.Prefix = "x"
>   OpenXml Cell.StyleIndex = "1"
>   OpenXml Cell.DataType = "s"
>   c.CellFormula Nothing

Required value = `'ABC-P-1000'`

---

Here is my code:

```
Public Shared Sub parseXLS(strFileName As String, sbTxtFromFile As StringBuilder)
    Call fncParseXLSXorXLSM(strFileName, sbTxtFromFile)
End Sub

Public Shared Function fncParseXLSXorXLSM(strFileName As String, sbTxtFromFile As StringBuilder) As StringBuilder

        sbTxtFromFile.Length = 0
        Dim intFirst As Integer = 1

        Try
            Using spreadsheetDocument__1 As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(strFileName, False)
                Dim workbookPart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument__1.WorkbookPart
                Dim sharedStringItemsArray As SharedStringItem() = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements(Of SharedStringItem)().ToArray()
                Dim sheets As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets = spreadsheetDocument__1.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets

                ' For each sheet, display the sheet information.
                For Each sheet As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement In sheets
                    For Each attr As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlAttribute In sheet.GetAttributes()
                        Debug.Print("{0}: {1}", attr.LocalName, attr.Value)
                        If attr.LocalName = "name" Then
                            sbTxtFromFile.Append(attr.Value)
                        End If
                    Next

                Next

                For Each worksheetPart As WorksheetPart In workbookPart.WorksheetParts
                    Dim reader As OpenXmlReader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart)
                    While reader.Read()
                        If reader.ElementType Is GetType(Cell) Then
                            Do
                                Dim c As Cell = DirectCast(reader.LoadCurrentElement(), Cell)

                                If c.DataType IsNot Nothing AndAlso c.DataType.Value.ToString = "SharedString" Then
                                    Dim ssi As SharedStringItem = sharedStringItemsArray(Integer.Parse(c.CellValue.InnerText))

                                    If Not ssi.Text Is Nothing Then
                                        If Not ssi.Text.Text Is Nothing Then
                                            If intFirst = 1 Then
                                                sbTxtFromFile.Append(ssi.Text.Text)
                                                intFirst = 2
                                            Else
                                                sbTxtFromFile.Append(Environment.NewLine & ssi.Text.Text)
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    Else
                                        If Not ssi.InnerText Is Nothing Then
                                            If intFirst = 1 Then
                                                sbTxtFromFile.Append(ssi.InnerText)
                                                intFirst = 2
                                            Else
                                                sbTxtFromFile.Append(Environment.NewLine & ssi.InnerText)
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    If Not c.CellValue Is Nothing Then
                                        If intFirst = 1 Then
                                            sbTxtFromFile.Append(c.CellValue.InnerText)
                                            intFirst = 2
                                        Else
                                            sbTxtFromFile.Append(Environment.NewLine & c.CellValue.InnerText)
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Loop While reader.ReadNextSibling()
                        End If
                        If sbTxtFromFile.Length > 0 Then
                            sbTxtFromFile.Append(Environment.NewLine)
                        End If
                    End While
                Next

            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.Message Like "The process cannot access the file '*" Then 'File in use
                sbTxtFromFile.Append("|11readonly11|")
            ElseIf ex.Message Like "Could not find*" Then 'File in use
                sbTxtFromFile.Append("|11notfound11|")
            Else
                sbTxtFromFile.Append("|11cannotread11|")
            End If
        End Try

        Return sbTxtFromFile

    End Function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get cell value with applied formatting (formatted cell value) with OpenXML SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8929799/11683)

Answer (score 0):

You can read cell style based on `StyleIndex` property, which will help you to determine formatting applied on the cell.

Use following method as an example and work around based on your need:

```
Private Shared Sub ReadCellFormat(cell As Cell, stylesheet As Stylesheet)
    If cell.StyleIndex.HasValue Then
        Debug.Print("Style found for the cell:")
        If stylesheet.CellFormats.Count.Value > cell.StyleIndex.Value Then
            Dim format As CellFormat = stylesheet.CellFormats.ElementAt(cell.StyleIndex.Value)
            If format.NumberFormatId.HasValue AndAlso format.NumberFormatId.Value > 0 Then
                Dim numberFormat As NumberingFormat = stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Single(Function(x As NumberingFormat) x.NumberFormatId.Value = format.NumberFormatId.Value)
                Debug.Print($"Format code: {numberFormat.FormatCode}")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

P.S: This method just reads the number format for the given cell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dipen.  As you can see in my example above, I already know the StyleIndex value, but it's just a meaningless number.  What I need are the actual values and prefixes, not just the number format.

Comment: @GoodJuJu What do you mean by `actual values`? Do you mean calculated values, after applying format/prefix?

Comment: ideally I want the calculated value, after applying the prefix, as it appears in excel.  If I cannot get that, I want to return something that tells me what the cell format is, e.g. Date, Currency, Custom etc.

Comment: @GoodJuJu I don't think it is possible to get calculated values. However, you can determine cell format based on `NumberFormatId` property.