# OpenXml unable to read integer with percentage symbol

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, openxml

Net core with Open XML. In my excel there is value 100%. I am trying to read as below

GetCellValue method

```
public static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument doc, Cell cell)
{
    if (cell.CellValue != null)
    {
        string value = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
        if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
        {
            return doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements.ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

GetCell method

```
 public static Cell GetCell(Worksheet worksheet, string columnName, uint rowIndex)
 {
     Row row = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex);

     if (row != null)
     {
         return row.Elements<Cell>().FirstOrDefault(c => string.Compare(c.CellReference.Value, columnName + rowIndex, true) == 0);
     }
     return null;
 }
```

I am reading as below.

```
 var data = OpenXmlReader.GetCellValue(spreadsheetDocument, OpenXmlReader.GetCell(workSheet, "E", 11));
```

The data is coming as 1 whereas actual value in my excel is 100%. I am not sure why this is not properly reading. Can someone please help me? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929799/how-to-get-cell-value-with-applied-formatting-formatted-cell-value-with-openxm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel, the display format of cells and the actual stored data format can be different. When you enter 75% into a cell formatted as a percentage, Excel stores it as a decimal, but when displayed, it still appears as a percentage.

[image]
[image]

We can read the format configured in this way from Open XML,and we can see that the read `NumberFormatId` is 43, and the `FormatCode` is `"_ * #,##0.00_ ;_ * \\-#,##0.00_ ;_ * \"-\"??_ ;_ @_ "`

[image]
[image]

However, this format is not found in the predefined in NumberFormatId [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.numberingformat?view=openxml-3.0.1). So we can set a corresponding format for the return value use OpenXml . Here is an example for you can be used as reference：

```
public static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument doc, Cell cell)
{
     if (cell.CellValue != null)
     {
         string value = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
         if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
         {
             return doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements.ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
         }
         else if (cell.StyleIndex != null)
         {
             var styleIndex = (int)cell.StyleIndex.Value;
             var cellFormat = (NumberingFormat)doc.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.ElementAt(styleIndex);
             var numberFormat = doc.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Elements<NumberingFormat>()
                 .Where(i => i.NumberFormatId.ToString() == cellFormat.NumberFormatId.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().FormatCode;
             if (numberFormat != null )
             {
                 var cellValue = double.Parse(value);
                 value = (cellValue * 100).ToString("0.00") + "%";
             }
         }
         return value;
     }
     return string.Empty;
}
```

Return data:

[image]